# AC circuit with no neutral output

Tags: electric-circuits

I was [referred here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/410027/206097) from the electrical engineering stackexchange, because my question is too theoretical.

Consider the following circuit:

[image]

Where $\varphi$ represents the phase of the AC power and the broken line represents a very long line, specifically of length $\frac v{120}$ meters where $v$ is the velocity at which the electric potential propagates through the ideal wire in $m/s$.

To me, having effectively no background in electricity, it looks like there will be voltage across the light bulb and in will light up despite not being connected to neutral at all. This sounds wrong, so I have two questions:

1. Would that really work?
2. Is there a way to shift the phase on the wire without having extending it to that length, which when you plug in $v=c$ works out to $2500km$?

Comment: You might be able to boil this idea down further.  Think about just an ideal wire connected to A/C.  There are spots in the wire with high and low potential, even though they are shorted directly together via the wire itself.

Comment: I don't see a light bulb in your diagram.

Comment: Where is the other side of the source connected? To an earth ground?

Answer (score 1):

Will it work?  Yes, but not much. You’ve basically constructed a quarter wave antenna. Current will flow due to the capacitance and inductance of the wire running out to the right.

(You’d get more current in the lamp if you got rid of the upper wire, but it’ll still “work” with that)

Unfortunately, you won’t get a lot of light. The 60Hz of power lines doesn’t radiate very well.

Answer (score 0):

Would this really work?  No, you don't have a circuit.  A circuit requires currents to return to the source.

Is there a way to shift the phase on the wire?  Yes, by choosing different types of wires you can affect the [velocity factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor).

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it is a bit simplistic (the voltage is going to propagate down both sides simultaneously), but you could certainly construct a circuit where the voltage takes a full cycle to propagate.  But that won't help you.

> Would that really work?

Nope.  In the regular circuit, you have a neutral being held at zero.  So for the period of time when the hot line is high, there's a large potential difference between the lines.  Significant current flows through the bulb for several milliseconds.

In the one above, lets imagine that the left side is at the high point of the phase and the right side is still at zero.  A tiny bit of current flows through the bulb.  Since the capacitance of the wire is very low, the voltage in it rises quickly.  There's no longer a voltage difference across the bulb and the current (and power) drop to zero almost immediately.